High current alternative to Adafruit Powerboost 1000C
I'm building a circuit containing an Arduino Nano which controls 28 WSB2812B LEDs, two speakers via a dfPlayer Mini each, and I'm thinking about adding three 12g mini Servos that will require reasonable torque.
I estimate the continuous current draw to be about 3200mA without the servos and 3700mA at peak. I'm not sure how much the additional current draw would be with servos (maybe an additional 2A).
This circuit belongs to a project that is handheld and mobile and it will be inside a casing. Ideally I want it to be rechargable via an USB-C port from the outside.
The problem is that originally I was thinking of powering everything through an Adafruit Powerboost 1000C but this board can't supply enough current. I have found this RetroPSU which I think does exactly what I need but it is not available anymore.
Can someone point me in the right direction here? There seem to be a million charge-controllers out there but they are all for low power stuff or don't have all the things I need.

With that much power consumption, you should rethink your design if you want it to be a mobile battery-powered device. There's no way that will last very long on a charge unless you use impractically large batteries.

Space and weight is not that big of an issue. Would there be options? I mean there are commercial devices such as large portable bluetooth speakers or other things that are portable and require a lot of power, so I imagine it must be possible somehow, right?

Technically I could use a 30Ah powerbank like this and hook it up via solderable USB connectors, but that seems a bit sketchy.

A proper low-power microcontroller instead of an arduino nano, for one thing. Consider if you need all those LEDs and if you need to be driving them at the current you[re running at, or if a lower current would work. See if you can do the thing you want without needing motors (which are really power-hungry).
